# What calculus book do you recommend?

Tags: calculus, analysis, book-recommendation, machine-learning, neural-networks

What calculus books should I read to have a good background for AI, especially neural networks? For example Apostol Calculus and Zorich Calculus are good? Suggest other books and courses, if you think they are better.

Comment: Neural networks is extremely broad. Please give more details about what you are interested in

Comment: I am new in AI and doesn't know very well all branches of neural networks, but i'm interested in RNN and CNN. I would like to advance in deep learning

Comment: You'll need linear algebra and multivariable calculus. It's not that calculus intensive though so just pick whatever you want.

Comment: Please do not post your questions [twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666829/calculus-for-ai).

Comment: Thanks, but there are so many books and it is very hard to choose one. Can you recommend some books and other resources?

Comment: If you are interested in the engineering side of things, you really only need your standard three semesters of calculus (US). There isn’t a need for analysis. If you are interested in theory, there are technical papers and also theoretical but not so technical. For the former, you need measure theory. For the latter, a semester of analysis at the level of Rudin PMA or Strichartz away of Analysis is probably enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to what @cyclotomicField said, if you're new to calculus [openstax](https://openstax.org/subjects/math) has multiple free calculus books. They might be helpful building up to multivariable calculus. I have used them a lot in my own studies.